# Gerar grid com vários registros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Bom dia, estou precisando fazer uma grid aonde preciso dizer exatamente o valor de cada linha dela baseada em uma coluna de uma tabela no banco, preciso de ajuda pois nunca fiz algo assim.

É uma aplicação web ASP.NET MVC utilizando o SQL Server como banco de dados.

Já tentei seguir esses passos porém não obtive resultado:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/d8dc9382-d5cb-4ada-a49f-2a9cd6a17d8f/preencher-textbox-com-dados-do-banco-sql-em-c?forum=clientept

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/pt-BR/a17a14e5-38dc-45f4-9473-c770208a5cd1/preencher-textbox-com-varios-dados-da-tabela?forum=vsvbasicpt

Comment: O que já tentou fazer ? poderia posta isso na pergunta ?

Comment: coloquei 2 links que eu estava estudando

Comment: Tudo bem. Sabemos o que tu olhou. Mas e como tu testou? Edita tua pergunta e adiciona o código, por gentileza, Jordan. (=

Comment: o projeto é confidencial, não me autorizaram a colar parte alguma do código dele internet afora =/